setting ir-keytable config at boot fails on a raspberry pi 0 (2 methods tested, systemd and rc.local)
I've setup ir-keytable and I use it with my IR-remote control.
I load the config which makes it work without pb by:
sudo ir-keytable -p all -s rc1
I can check it running with:
sudo evtest
and everything's alright.
Now I want to load the config at boot. I've written a file named my_boot.service:
[Unit]
Description=init ir-keytable 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ir-keytable  -p all -s rc1
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Then
sudo systemctl enable my_boot.service
sudo systemctl start my_boot.service

When I reboot, the config has not been loaded.
I must type
sudo ir-keytable -v -p all -s rc1 
again to make my IR-remote control work.
The same thing happens when I use /etc/rc.local :
/usr/bin/ir-keytable  -p all -s rc1
exit 0

It has worked setting Type=Idle and now it doesn't work again : Found no device rc1, Failed with result 'exit-code'. But the command works perfectly in the prompt after reboot.

Don't use sudo in system service files, they are run root (but this is unlikely to be the cause of your problem).  Also have a look at systemctl status my_boot.  I realize this is not exactly the same as the other question, but it is close enough and you are obviously trying to deal with the same issue.  If you have succeeded with the other one, then please edit in a link to it and explain how that now works but this does not.

I tried both with and without sudo /usr/bin etc.. same fail

I've also tried to type the command /usr/bin/ir-keytable -v -p all -s rc1 in etc/rc.local unsuccesfully

my question is marked 'this question has answers here'. that is not correct. the answer is about the command print and the terminal where it should be displayed, nothing in relation with the current question.

If you would like this re-opened, please edit in the output from sudo systemctl status my_boot and sudo journalctl -u my_boot.

the solution to set Type=Idle

I've re-opened this so you can add that as an answer yourself -- but please don't put SOLVED in question titles.  Instead, use the big check mark on the upper left side of the answer that worked.  If this is your own answer, you may need to wait 24 hours before you can tick it.

now it doesn't work and I don't understand why. it returns Failed with result 'exit-code' Found no device rc1

I would guess that's because even in running it as late as you can at boot, there are circumstances under which it won't initialize because something isn't ready.  I've never used IR with a Pi so I can't help you there, but you need to determine what those circumstances are so you can either make the service somehow dependent on it, or else do loop with a decent pause (eg. thirty seconds) that will retry on failure a fixed number of times (there's a way to do that directly w/ systemd, you can set a service to auto restart on fail, but make sure you include some delay or it will happen...

...too rapidly and sysd will stop it happening).

thks so much goldilocks.I'll investigate these suggestions.

Please accept your own answer so this does not keep getting resurrected to the front page as unanswered.

The solution is to write the ir-keytable command in a shell (named remote.sh for example)  :
sudo /usr/bin/ir-keytable -p a -s rc1

and run the shell in a python script (named boot_ir.py) :
import os
os.system('sh remote.sh')

then start the python script in a service :
[Unit]
Description=My custom command
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Execstart= usr/bin/python /home/pi/boot_ir.py
WorkingDirectory= home/pi

[Install]
WantedBy=custom.target

Here is the service custom.target :
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Target
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
AllowIsolate=yes

This works !
